# Should I invest in US bond ETF as a US Non-resident Alien? If so, how should I manage the bond portfolio?

Tags: capital-gains-tax, dividends, investment-strategies, bond-etf

I’m currently investing in US market using IBKR with 70% index ETF (QQQ, VOO, etc.) and 30% bond ETF split (only BND at the moment).

- I’ve done this for two years
- I’m aware that a 30% withholding tax is applied to all dividends from my bond ETF which makes the investment less attractive

My questions are:

- Should I stop investing in US bond ETFs since the 30% dividend tax makes it less attractive? If so, what alternatives do I have for my 30% bond portfolio target?
- Though bond is generally considered safe, my BND has fluctuated quite a lot in the past two years (20%-ish fluctuation). Currently I buy monthly with fixed amount. I wonder if I should be more selective in the time of buying, or I should continue with regular monthly buying? (dollar averaging)

Thank you!

Comment: Questions seeking specific product/service recommendations are off-topic here. Sorry. Please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Sorry about that! I've made edits to make the questions more general. Please let me know if further changes are needed.